# Android ListView after rows are created

Tags: android, listview, events

I'm working on an android application.
Using AsyncTask, I load my data from database. Then using an ArrayAdapter I show all data on the screen.
Now I need to start getting more information about these rows from my server and then refresh those rows. So I need to be able to get notified when ListView have displayed rows to the user.

Please tell me how can I get notified that ListView rows are displayed to start loading more info from my server.

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged()` see this answer its usage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example

Comment: @Jimi: Thanks for your comment. but as the accepted answer says: we can only use notifyDataSetChanged() while using add, delete, ...